# Strange mouse movement issue on linux

Tags: linux, mouse

I have a P85s Bloody gaming mouse. After installing Pop!_Os I have a bizarre mouse movement problem

When I move the cursor fast, everything is OK, But when I move It regularly, It seems like something Is blocking the way of the mouse cursor when moving. sometimes it stops moving suddenly

The down and Right movement is OK, The problem on Top and Left movement

You can watch the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FoP9IY8WzqU)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community if I could explain what is going on, I would. that's why I link to a video!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with a *Bloody P91* mouse on Manjaro. My solution was to download some [driver off GITLab](https://gitlab.com/C0rn3j/a4tech_bloody_p85_driver) and every time I log in run the software and change every setting.

It's not a perfect solution, so answers containing a better one are still welcome.